# Is the following set of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am using Anton's Elementary Linear Algebra book (8e) and trying to do exercise set 5.3, question 2a

It gives the vectors $(4,-1,2)$, $(-4,10,2)$ and asks if they are linearly dependent .

My final answer as a matrix is

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1 & 0 & 11/18 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 4/9 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

therefore I get coefficient $1 = 0-11/18 (t)$
                coefficient  $2 = -4/9 (t)$

so based on this I'd say the vectors are linear dependent as they are both multiples of (t), but I am wrong and unsure why.

Is anyone able to shed some light on where I went wrong ?

I start out by making a matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}4 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\ -4 & 10 & 2 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

and then proceed elimination to get it to row echelon form

arfghh sorry it has formatted ugly an dIm unsure how to get it into a matrix appearance

Answer (score 1):

They are linearly **independent** since the minor is non-zero, i.e :

$$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -1 \\ -4 & 10 \end{pmatrix}=36\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $(4,-1,2)$ and $(-4,10,2$) were linearly dependent, there would be scalars $a,b$ (not both zero ) so that:

$a(4,-1,2) + b(-4,10,2) = (0,0,0)$, or, equivalently:

$4a - 4b = 0\\10b - a = 0\\2a+2b = 0$

It is easy to see that were this so, we would have to have (from the first equation), $a = b$, and from the third equation $a = -b$, which unfortunately means $a = b = 0$, which is a no-go.

In general, a set of just two vectors is linearly dependent if one vector is a scalar multiple of the other, in this case, we can see that no scalar multiple of $(4,-1,2)$ yields $(-4,10,2)$. To match the first coordinates, the scalar would have to be $-1$, to match the third coordinates, the scalar would have to be $1$, to match the second coordinates, the scalar would have to be $-10$ or $-\frac{1}{10}$. That just can't happen.

Row-reducing a matrix (which need only be a 2x3 matrix in this situation) is rather over-kill for this type of problem. But if you insist:

$\begin{bmatrix}4&-1&2\\-4&10&2\end{bmatrix}$

$\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}4&-1&2\\0&9&4\end{bmatrix}$ (adding row 1 to row 2)

$\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&9&4\end{bmatrix}$ (multiplying row 1 by 1/4)

$\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&\frac{4}{9}\end{bmatrix}$ (multiplying row 2 by 1/9)

$\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&0&\frac{11}{18}\\0&1&\frac{4}{9}\end{bmatrix}$ (adding 1/4 row 2 to row 1)

we are now in rref, and we have no zero rows, so our original rows are linearly independent (no scalar multiple of the first row can ever give the second row, because any such scalar multiple would still have a 0 in coordinate 2, and the second column entry of row two is non-zero).

Comment: thanks for this…the part I don't understand is why isn't the bottom equivalent to saying  0a + 1b + 4/9 c  = 0, which then would be b = -4/9 c  ?

Comment: I see you mention "we have no zero rows" ? What is the significance of having one or not ? I'm guessing it indicates something specific ?

Comment: Matrices are not equations. A system of linear equations has a matrix that goes along with it, but in this situation a matrix is more like a "vector of vectors". You need to review linear independence and linear dependence and try to understand what they mean. If we form a matrix out of a collection of vectors, by making each vector a row, and we row-reduce the matrix to rref, getting zero rows means we have a linearly dependent set of vectors (this is analogous to having an unnecessary equation in a system).

Comment: Thanks @David Wheeler. I think I have established a tripping point so will ask a new question